# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT w/Billing Account Enabled

Tags: php, geocoding

I am using the `Geocoding API`, and am receiving `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` and I have enabled my billing account, which should give me over 100k queries. I am doing about 2500 or less. It seems to happen when I am processing many items in a php loop, but not for each item - for example.

1. OK
2. OK
3. OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
4. OK
5. OK

So it doesn't appear I am actually over the limit, but that's the XML returned for the transaction. If I process the same transaction in a URL it works with no issue.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Pace your application or submit the requests in smaller groups.  Solutions include using a cron job to distribute the requests throughout the day, or adding a small delay between requests.

From: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits

> If you exceed the usage limits you will get an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status
>   code as a response.
>
> This means that the web service will stop providing normal responses
>   and switch to returning only status code OVER_QUERY_LIMIT until more
>   usage is allowed again. This can happen:
>
> Within a few seconds, if the error was received because your
>   application sent too many requests per second.